# MobileFirst 7.1 analytics unable to capture custom messages

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

Hi I am new to the Mobile First analytic .  I Created one Mobile First native android project and now i want to integrate analytics with that. I am mentioning code snippet using for analytics.

WLAnalytics.setContext(this); // Inside onCreate Meathod of my activity
    WLAnalytics.enable();

```
String json = "any";
try {

    WLAnalytics.log("Custom event", new JSONObject(json));


} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
WLAnalytics.send();
```

and  i followed below mentioned article for that

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/moving-production/operational-analytics/

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/moving-production/operational-analytics/#clientLogs

Comment: Do you get any errors in the server log? What is your build number of MFPF 7.1?

Comment: Hi @IdanAdar  thanks for reply i am not getting any logs for that but can you tell me how to check custom message from analytics console.

Comment: Do you get any analytics at all in the analytics console?  Are you sure that the analytics JNDI properties and credentials are set correctly?

Comment: I am getting debug logs in console but i am unable to create analytics  chart of message. How can i create a chart of custom events which i am passing to analytic server by using  WLAnalytics.log("Custom event", new JSONObject(json));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WLAnalytics.setContext(this);

WLAnalytics analytic = new WLAnalytics();
try {
    analytic.log("this", new JSONObject("{\"android\" : \"message\"}"));
} catch(Exception e){

}
analytic.send();
```

You are not creating a JSON message. My key is 'android' and my value is 'message'